# ruby hashes with files list from a directory of mp3

Tags: ruby

I have thousands of mp3 named like this: `record-20091030.mp3`, `record-20091130.mp3` etc
I want to parse and obtain a ruby hash `year->month->[days] (hash, hash, array)`

what wrong whit this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

files = Dir.glob("mp3/*.mp3")

@result = Hash.new


files.each do |file|
  date = file.match(/\d{8}/).to_s
  year = date[0,4]
  month = date[4,2]
  day = date[6,2]

  @result[year.to_i] = Hash.new
  @result[year.to_i][month.to_i] = Array.new
  @result[year.to_i][month.to_i] << day 
end

puts @result
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the stored values (with `Hash.new` and `Array.new`) on every iteration of the loop, you should only be doing this if the hash/array is nil, e.g:

```
  @result[year.to_i] ||= Hash.new
  @result[year.to_i][month.to_i] ||= Array.new
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make some fixes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

files = Dir.glob("mp3/*.mp3")

@result = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

files.each do |file|
  date = file[-12..-4]
  year, month, day = date.scan(/(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})/).first.map(&:to_i)

  @result[year][month][day] = file
end

@result.each_pair { |name, val| puts "#{name} #{val}"  }

# => 2009 {10=>{30=>"mp3/record-20091030.mp3"}, 
#          11=>{30=>"mp3/record-20091130.mp3"}}
#    2010 {1=>{23=>"mp3/record-20100123.mp3"}}
```